# Amazon EC2 Move On Demand instance to Reserved

Tags: amazon-ec2

Am moving a Win2003 server onto Amazon.  I'd like to build it on the On Demand instance first, then if all goes well, move to a Reserved.

Question:  Is there any way to move from On Demand to Reserved, or will I have to manually rebuild the machine again.

Its not an easy build and I don't want to have to do it again :-)

Comment: "Its not an easy build and I don't want to have to do it again :-)"
You're in for a world of hurt if you can't rebuild your instance. It will at some point crash in EC2 i can almost guarantee it will happen. Make sure you have a backup to easily recover from a failure.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I am documenting my build as I go.  Whats your strategy for recovering from failure..am on a non EBS backed route, and will have important data and legacy db (MSDE) on the VM.

Comment: I generally have everything backed up in S3. I have a non-interactive script to start the instance from the latest backup so in the event of a failure i just execute a command and its up in ~3 min. In most cases the servers are on loadbalancers and recovery is automated because of the autoscaling group and loadbalancer checks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole on-demand vs. reserved instance thing is really just a matter of how you're billed by Amazon. The actual EC2 instances themselves are exactly the same.

Just purchase a reserved instance in the same AZ as your server is in currently, and your billing will be automatically changed to reflect the reserved rates.

Comment: +1 for this. I was hugely confused by this the first time. Wish Amazon had something in the console saying something like "this reserved instance is currently being filled by instance i-29304293"

Comment: Amazon seems to have their own little ecosystem for terminology and functionality...makes their documentation a little sketchy to follow. Annoying.

Comment: So, You saying that we need to launch another instance and have two instead one in order to get billed as Reserved one on the first one?

Comment: No, if you reserve an instance, you get credit for it if you have an instance running that matches the reservation criteria.

Comment: @EEAA will it be reflected on the 'cost explorer' > daily cost report instantly?

Comment: @AnthonyKong what's the min duration for any RI purchase to reflect within "cost explorer" reports? it didn't reflect even after 6 Hrs for my case; I've been asked to check after 24 Hrs by the tech-support person.

Comment: Only on the next day, it starts reflecting in "Monthly EC2 running hours costs and usage(Daywise)"-Group By: Purchase Options; usage hours are plotted separately as 'On demand' or 'Reserved'